# FMDatabaseQueue was called reentrantly error

Tags: fmdb

I have a wrapper around my sqlite database which creates objects and handles all database queries. It contains only SELECT queries. It is nicely factored into reusable pieces and is working well.

Recently I added a query that is running slowly (multiple joins) and so I wanted to run it on a background queue.

I created an FMDatabaseQueue and wrapped all my calls to `db.executeQuery` inside `queue.inDatabase { db in ... }`.

But when FMDB  detects that I am calling `inDatabase` from within another `inDatabase` call, it bombs out:

```
inDatabase: was called reentrantly on the same queue, which would lead to a deadlock.
```

What is the correct way to handle this? It seems that I need to restructure my code to ensure that there is never a nested call to the db, but I don't understand why, since sqlite has no problem with simultaneous reads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FMDatabaseQueue can't detect if you're going to do an update or start a transaction or if you're only doing reads. So it always says "nope" to reentrant calls.

If you are only doing reads, you might instead use a pool of connections.

Comment: Thanks, did not know about FMDatabasePool!